# Removing Volumes/ Loop Device post snapd removal/purge

Tags: volume-control

I have discovered some remaining "volumes" or "Loop Device" after purging snapd. One is nearly a half gigabyte so my question is can I remove these to free up additional memory.
I now have 5-6 GB free under filesystem root after removing snapd but want to completely get rid of anything unnecessary that was related to snapd. Attached are screenshots showing the volumes and properties.

[image: Volume Info 1]

[image: Volume Info 2]

[image: Volume Info 3]

Comment: Did you reboot since you removed snapd? Looks like you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: rebooting clears out the loop devices/volumes....